# Check integral to convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

How can this integral be checked for convergence? $$\int_\limits{0}^\limits{1}\frac{1}{e^x x}$$

Comment: As $e^x$ is fairly "tame" on $[0,1]$ (continuous, thereby bounded), can you find a bound (upper or lower, as necessary) of $\frac{1}{e^x x}$ on $[0,1]$ with another function *without* the term $e^x$, for which you already know the result?

Comment: $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{xe^x} > \int_0^1\frac{1}{xe} = \infty$, hence original integral diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Note that on the interval $[0,1]$ that $e^x\leq x+5$. This implies that $\frac{1}{x+5}\leq \frac{1}{e^x}$. Then using this for the integral, we get that:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\int_0^1\frac{1}{xe^x}dx\geq \int_0^1\frac{1}{x(x+5)}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{5}\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}dx-\frac{1}{5}\int_0^1\frac{1}{x+5}dx\quad \text{Via partial fraction decomposition}\\
&=\frac{1}{5}(\ln(1)-\ln(0))-\frac{1}{5}(\ln(6)-\ln(5))=\infty
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Therefore the integral diverges.

Comment: This is correct, but wouldn't it be easier to use $e^x\leq e$ on $[0,1]$?